# Are results from math operations on Double exactly repeatable?

Tags: java, floating-point, java-8, double

I have a complex data processing algorithm implemented using Java 8 and using Double as data type. Given the same input (many hundred thousand database rows) this algorithm outputs different Double values. Sometimes value **a** is returned, sometimes value **b**. These two values alternate each execution. The difference between **a** and **b** is ~0.0001. I am aware that Double datatype does not grant exact values like Decimal does. I am not sure, however, if it grants *repeatable* results, assuming exactly same input. I.e. would it be possible that rounding policies are applied in a non-consistent way? My purpose here would be to explain why I get different values with same input.

Other details: I am using Tomcat 8 runtime environment, deployment done on SAP HCP. Datatype at database level is *Decimal*, we need Double at Java level for historical reasons.

Comment: I can't answer, but if you want absolute repeatability, try googling "fpstrict"

Comment: Applying exactly the same sequence of operations on the same system should always result in the same answer; using `fpstrict` would guarantee the same result on all systems. Are you sure that there is no non-determinism in the input?

Comment: Not having `fpstrict` should not make it undetermistic on a given platform, though, just make it portable across platforms, right? @MarcoBolis

Comment: Absolutely so, `fpstrict` is about repeatability **across** different platformss. Sorry if the comment sounded misleading...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Order matters. If the order of the database rows processed is not the same every time it can yield different results. Here is a simple example:

```
double d1 = 0.1;
double d2 = 0.2;
System.out.println(d1 + d1 + d2 + d2); 
System.out.println(d1 + d2 + d2 + d1);
```

Answer (score 9):

Given the same input, floating point number calculations (on the same platform) will result in the same output.

However, you may get different results if you feed in the input numbers in different orders (even though that would not make a difference mathematically). Maybe that is what is happening here (seeing that you pull the numbers out of a relational database, which has no defined order unless you explicitly sort). Same thing can happen if you have parallel computations using multiple CPU and the data is divided and combined differently each time.

Answer (score 4):

For strictfp the Java Language Specification fully defines the results of all simple arithmetic on doubles, regardless of platform.

Some `java.lang.Math` methods are allowed to produce slightly different results for some operations. If you need reproducible results, use `java.lang.StrictMath` instead.

As noted in a comment below, java.lang.Math.cos is an example of a function whose result can change. The [API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#cos(double)) says "The computed result must be within 1 ulp of the exact result. Results must be semi-monotonic."

Comment: Isn't `StrictMath` about portability between architectures (but non-strict math should still be deterministic and repeatable as long as you stick with the same CPU/OS/JVM)?

Comment: @Thilo I would generally expect repeatability, but it is not absolutely guaranteed without strictfp. At least in theory, a hotspot compiler could vary its optimizations based on observed performance, causing run-to-run variations. That said, the results the OP describes are much more likely to be due to something like a multi-threading bug in the program.

Comment: I have just experienced different results being returned by `Math.cos` depending on whether the app is running Iava 8 or Java 11 - most likely a result of [Improve Aarch64 Intrinsics](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/315)

Answer (score 3):

This is an example from the doc of `Collectors.averagingDouble`:

`The average returned can vary depending upon the order in which values are recorded, due to accumulated rounding error in addition of values of differing magnitudes`.

The key words here are `depending upon the order`. This is because average double uses Kahan summation under the hood (for better results and less lost precision).

The same counts for any `other` double operation. The order in which those operations are applied could have an impact on the final result (because of rounding).

Here is an example:

```
  Double d1 = Stream.of(10000.0D, 3.14159D, 2.71828D).collect(Collectors.averagingDouble(x -> x)); 
  Double d2 = Stream.of(3.14159D, 10000.0D, 2.71828D).collect(Collectors.averagingDouble(x -> x));


  System.out.println(d1); // 3335.2866233333334
  System.out.println(d2); // 3335.286623333333
```

Same numbers applied in different order gives a different result (precision is now different)